# Open URL (In IOS app) form Mopub Order in external browser

Tags: ios, browser, external, mopub

Order Created in Mopub.

HTML creative:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.domain.com/image.png" width="100%" height="100%"><a/>
```

Works all fine but the URL is opening inside the app. What do I have to change in the creative code to open the URL in the external browser?

Comment: This question seems to have the polar opposite issue, maybe something in here will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041219/android-need-mopub-ad-to-open-in-webview-when-clicked-on

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't find a solution here.

Answer (score 2):

> 3.B.6. Native Browser Clicks In order to do tracking in the OS’s native browser, partners may choose to use the native browser click
>   functionality supported by the MoPub SDK.
>
> You can target this functionality via the
>   banner.ext.nativebrowserclick field on the request. If set to 1 it is
>   supported by the requesting SDK.
>
> In the creative returned in the adm field, this behavior can be
>   triggered by setting the click through URL in the following format
>   using a custom URI pattern (this custom URI will open the URL in the
>   native OS browser) :
>
> mopubnativebrowser://navigate?url=
>
> IMPORTANT: Ensure that ‘http://’ or ‘https://’ is included in the
>   intended landing page URL.
>
> ie: “mopubnativebrowser://navigate?url=http://www.mopub.com”

This is from:
https://dev.twitter.com/mopub-demand/overview/openrtb